# How to get trigger to listen properly

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, eventtrigger

I am having a hard time getting my trigger to respond properly. I have plenty that are working but one of them isn't and I can't understand why.

Here is my AppController class

```
class ProjectOrder.View.AppController extends Backbone.View
  initialize: ->
    @promptOfficeSearch()

  promptOfficeSearch: ->
    officeSearch = new ProjectOrder.View.OfficeSearch
    officeSearch.on 'createOffice', @promptOfficeCreate
    officeSearch.on 'createTicket', @promptTicketCreate
    officeSearch.on 'accountAndTicketExist', @killProcessAccountExists


 promptOfficeCreate: (serial) ->
   @officeModel = new ProjectOrder.Model.OfficeModel()
   @officeModel.set('serial_number', serial)

   officeCreate = new ProjectOrder.View.OfficeCreator({model: @officeModel})
   officeCreate.on 'createTicketOffAccount', @promptTicketCreate

 promptTicketCreate: (model) ->
   console.log 'promptTicketCreate'
   model = model || @officeModel
   ticketModel = new ProjectOrder.Model.TicketModel()
   new ProjectOrder.View.TicketCreator({ticketModel: ticketModel, officeModel: model})

 killProcessAccountExists: (ticket_id) ->
   msg = document.createElement 'div'
   msg.className = 'account-exists-msg'
   msg.innerHTML = "Account already exists. Redirecting to ticket #{ticket_id}..."

   $('#create-order-div').append(msg)
   setTimeout((->
     window.location = "/pto/#{ticket_id}"
   ), 2000)
```

All of the triggers from the officeSearch object in the promptOfficeSearch function work properly. They are all triggered as follows, respectively:

```
@trigger 'createOffice', serial
@trigger 'createTicket', data.model[0]
@trigger 'accountAndTicketExist', data.model
```

But with the officeCreate object in the promptOfficeCreate, it does not respond to the createTicketOffAccount event which is registered in the submitOffice ajax success callback in my OfficeCreator class:

```
class ProjectOrder.View.OfficeCreator extends Backbone.View
  template: _.template($("#OfficeCreator").html())
  id: 'office-creator'
  events:
    'click .submit'     : 'submitOffice'

  initialize: ->
    @render()

  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template(@model.toJSON()))
    $('#create-order-div').append(@$el)

  submitOffice: ->
    @setModelData()
    @model.save(null,{
      success: (model) =>
        @trigger 'createTicketOffAccount', model
        #@$el.remove()
      error: ->
        alert 'error'
    })

  setModelData: ->
    @model.set({
      office_name:    $('#office').val()
      doctor_name:    $('#doctor').val()
      emr:            $('#has-emr').is(':checked')
      forms_builder:  $('#has-forms').is(':checked')
      iehr:           $('#has-iehr').is(':checked')
      clipboard:      $('#has-clip').is(':checked')
      specialty_id:  $('#specialty').val()
    })
```

any ideas why my trigger is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need fat arrows on all the methods in your `AppController` class.

When this event fires:

```
officeSearch.on 'createOffice', @promptOfficeCreate
```

the `promptOfficeCreate` function gets invoked as a normal function as opposed to a method bound to your controller instance as `this`, so when this happens:

```
officeCreate.on 'createTicketOffAccount', @promptTicketCreate
```

`@promptTicketCreate` is undefined and the event binding doesn't wire up properly.

Comment: I'm not binding my event handler to the model instance. It's binded to `officeCreate` which is an instance of OfficeCreator (which is a Backbone.View)...

Comment: Yup, you are absolutely right. The method gets called on the wrong object losing `this`'s focus on the AppController. Thanks for the help!